# p-fileUpload change default icon of the control for multiple controls

Tags: angular, primeng

I am having two file uploads on a form, where I want to apply different icon for each control.

```html
<p-fileUpload
  mode="basic"
  title="Photo"
  name="Photo[]"
  accept="image/*"
></p-fileUpload>

<p-fileUpload
  mode="basic"
  name="signature[]"
  accept="image/*"
></p-fileUpload>
```

Currently I am able to do only one control. I tried with `name` and `title` but it didn't work.

```scss
:host ::ng-deep .p-fileupload-choose {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  content: url('../autograph.png') !important;
}
```

Also, I heard `ng-deep` was deprecated. Is there any other way to do this?

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/uvubg7?file=angular.json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to override the [`chooseicon`](https://primeng.org/fileupload#api.fileupload.templates.chooseicon) template of the component:

```html
<p-fileUpload mode="basic" title="Photo" name="Photo[]" accept="image/*">
  <ng-template pTemplate="chooseicon">
    <img class="icon" src="../autograph.png" />
  </ng-template>
</p-fileUpload>

<p-fileUpload mode="basic" name="signature[]" accept="image/*">
  <ng-template pTemplate="chooseicon">
    <img class="icon" src="../something-else.png" />
  </ng-template>
</p-fileUpload>
```

```css
.icon {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-scrollpanel-demo-yp5mf7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)